# How to add A New Artifact use WSO2 Configurable Governance Artifacts with API?

Tags: wso2, artifact, wso2-governance-registry

### I want to add A New Artifact use WSO2 Configurable Governance Artifacts with API, wrote codes  this:

```
public static Registry getRegistry() {
            Registry governanceRegistry = null;
            String url = "https://localhost:9443/registry";
            String username = "admin";
            String password = "admin";
            System.setProperty("carbon.repo.write.mode", "true");
            try {
                RemoteRegistry rootRegistry = new RemoteRegistry(new URL(url), username,
                        password);
                governanceRegistry = GovernanceUtils.getGovernanceUserRegistry(
                        rootRegistry, username);
            } catch (RegistryException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return governanceRegistry;
        }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
            try {
                Registry registry = WSRegistryClient.getRegistry();
                GovernanceUtils.loadGovernanceArtifacts((UserRegistry) registry);
                GenericArtifactManager artifactManager = new GenericArtifactManager(
                        registry, "endpoint");
                GenericArtifact artifact = artifactManager
                        .newGovernanceArtifact(new QName("http://www.example.com/", "endpoint_1"));
                artifact.setAttribute("Name", "endpoint");
                artifact.setAttribute("Version", "1.0.0");
                artifact.setAttribute("Address", "http://www.google.com");
                artifactManager.addGenericArtifact(artifact);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

  1.

---

### " the "endpoint"is exit the Artifact Type like this:

```
<artifactType type="application/vnd.wso2-endpoint+xml" shortName="endpoint" singularLabel="Endpoint"
              pluralLabel="Endpoints" hasNamespace="false" iconSet="2">
    <storagePath>/trunk/endpoints/@{overview_name}</storagePath>
    <nameAttribute>overview_name</nameAttribute>
    <lifecycle>EndpointLifeCycle</lifecycle>
    <ui>
        <list>
            <column name="Name">
                <data type="path" value="overview_name" href="@{storagePath}"/>
            </column>
            <column name="Version">
                <data type="path" value="overview_version" href="@{storagePath}"/>
            </column>
        </list>
    </ui>
    <content>
        <table name="Overview">
            <field type="text" required="true" readonly="true">
                <name>Name</name>
            </field>
            <field type="text" required="true">
                <name>Version</name>
            </field>
            <field type="text" required="true">
                <name>Address</name>
            </field>
            <field type="text">
                <name>Environment</name>
            </field>
        </table>
    </content>
</artifactType>
```

  2.

---

### when i runing the code but got exception:

```
org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.exception.GovernanceException: Version is a required field, Please provide a value for this parameter.
    at org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.common.GovernanceArtifactManager.validateArtifact(GovernanceArtifactManager.java:940)
    at org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.common.GovernanceArtifactManager.addGovernanceArtifact(GovernanceArtifactManager.java:184)
    at org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.generic.GenericArtifactManager.addGenericArtifact(GenericArtifactManager.java:217)
    at cn.oge.kkm.alg.template.AlgTemplateHandler.put(AlgTemplateHandler.java:66)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.HandlerManager.put(HandlerManager.java:2503)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.HandlerLifecycleManager.put(HandlerLifecycleManager.java:945)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistry.put(EmbeddedRegistry.java:697)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.caching.CacheBackedRegistry.put(CacheBackedRegistry.java:550)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.putInternal(UserRegistry.java:827)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.access$1000(UserRegistry.java:60)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry$11.run(UserRegistry.java:803)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry$11.run(UserRegistry.java:800)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.put(UserRegistry.java:800)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.resource.services.utils.AddResourceUtil.addResource(AddResourceUtil.java:88)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.resource.services.ResourceService.addResource(ResourceService.java:292)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.invokeServiceClass(RPCUtil.java:212)
```

---

### Did I miss something? or something wrong use the Configurable Governance Artifacts with API?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is the org.wso2.carbon.governance.api dependency version that you use?

Comment: The api dependency version is :4.6.2-SNAPSHOT

Comment: Can you try with already released version like 4.6.1 or 4.6.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking at you code I assume you have done a small mistake. Please change the following code,

```
artifact.setAttribute("overview_name", "endpoint");
artifact.setAttribute("overview_version", "1.0.0");
artifact.setAttribute("overview_address", "http://www.google.com");
```

Other than dont use snapshot versions, please use release versions as much as possible.

There is a more easier way, you can use [Governance REST API](https://docs.wso2.com/display/Governance510/Governance+REST+API) to add a artifacts.